# How to get mocha to not require file from src/

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I need to set some environment variables before I `require` any files from the `src` folder. I created a `test/configure-test.js` file that sets env variables I need, however it looks like file `src/server.js` is loaded before that.

I know I can put env vars on the script start line in package.json but I'd rather have it in code to make it easier to run individual tests. The reason I have to do it in this order is that one of the libraries I rely on (newrelic) has side effects just by requiring it.

I do have a mocha.opts file with this:

```
--harmony
--reporter
spec
./test/*-test.js
```

Seems like no matter what I do `src/server.js` loads first

Comment: "to make it easier to run individual tests" is not the recommended practice because you are not writing an app to test it; testing an app is an integral part of the sdlc not the end goal so doing something just so that you could run a test is not at all a good practice.

You can try lazy loading a module with a npm package by the name require-lazy-loader and see if it serves your purpose.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. My question is not about app code. My question is about mocha behavior. Why does it load a file from `src/` when there's no instructions present for it to do so and how do I get it to stop.

Comment: I haven't misunderstood your question at all. You are just expecting a different behavior than is normal from the underlying platform itself, which, in this case, is about a single package that when required causes behavior that you don't want so the only solution is to lazy load the package. Mocha or mocha-opts cannot change the behavior of node and it is not supposed to either just because there is a test!

Comment: So node always loads files from src automatically?

Comment: I don't think it is node knowing the src folder, it is the module.js package doing that. You might have seen 'module.js' in many error stack path. The methods of importance are Load and Compile of the module.js but you may check out the _resolveLookupPaths and findPath methods of module.js to find if you can redirect the load.

Comment: I have this problem in node 4, similar logic in node 8 doesn't exhibit this behavior though, I'm able to set environment variable in a spec prior to anything being loaded from src

Comment: Can you share more code / the directory structure, please? Seems like it's possible, but I'm kind of an amateur & can't think of a way from the provided data.

Comment: @LevKuznetsov if it works in node 8 then it could just be that the spec file is not being read or is in the wrong path